# how to use array to create images in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, document.write

I want to use array to create some images and also attach a function to each image.
    I'm new to javascript, there may have many syntax errors, 
    your correction will be highly appreciated. 
    Here is my code below. Me and my TA worked on this for hours
    but still cannot make it works, anyone have a clue about this?

```
function changeImage() {
    var i = 0;
    element = document.getElementById(myimage[i]); // here I want it call every id or content in that array.
    if (element.src.match("bulbon")) {
        element.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    }
    else {
        element.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}

var myimage = new Array();
myimage[0] = 0;
myimage[1] = 1;
myimage[2] = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < myimage.length;) {
    document.write("<img id=\"myimage[i]\" src=\"pic_bulboff.gif\" onmouseover=\"changeImage()\" width=\"20\" height=\"36\" />");
    i++; //in the img id=myimage[i] part, I want give each image I created a unique id, so my function can work on each image.
}​
```

Comment: thanks Matt for editing the format for me

Comment: you are now giving the images all the same id (a literal `myImage[i]`). You need to put the value of that variable there. And '0','1','2' are probably invalid ids, better start them with a letter. But you may not want to use ids at all, you could just use a class to target these images. Then you can do away with the document.write altogether and just have static HTML.

Comment: Tell me how are you calling the function changeImage() and are you sure the code you posted above is not missing any parenthesis ?

Comment: Why are you setting each array element's value equal to its index? That makes the whole array redundant since looking up `myindex[i]` will just return the same value as `i`. @Thilo - id attributes can start with digits in [html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id).

Comment: In my actual website, I have to create 400 of this images, so I think array might be a neat way to do it. what do you mean use a class to target these images? can you give an example? @Thilo

Comment: Shouldn't your array hold the src of each image rather than a number?

Comment: And in the onclick-handler, do you really want to change all images, or just the one being clicked on?

Comment: just change one being triggered.@Thilo

Comment: since all the 400 images use the same image source, I just put the source in the for loop under document.write..      all I want is giving every image a unique id, so the function can work on every single image alone.  @nnnnnn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images don't need an id attribute at all to work with the `changeImage()` function that you've shown, since it seems just to be trying to swap the image source of whichever image had a `mouseover` event. You can instead make use of the `this` keyword to get a reference to the "current" image.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
    document.write("<img src=\"pic_bulboff.gif\" onmouseover=\"changeImage(this)\" width=\"20\" height=\"36\" />");
}​

function changeImage(element) {
    if (element.src.indexOf("bulbon")!=-1) {
        element.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    }
    else {
        element.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}
```

Note that normally the [`.match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is used with a regular expression to return an array of the parts of your source string that matched the regex, but if you just want to test whether your string matches a regex without worrying about exactly what the match was then you should use `.test()` - or in your case since you're not using a regex at all it's probably more efficient to use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

If you wanted a function to be able to process *all* of your images, you should give them a common class and then use the [`.getElementsByClassName()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
    document.write('<img class="someClass" src="pic_bulboff.gif" onmouseover="changeImage(this)" width="20" height="36" />');
}​

function someFunction() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        // do something with elements[i]
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to escape all the double-quotes in a string literal with backslashes if the string was quoted with single-quotes.

**EDIT - In response to the comments:**

The code above definitely works, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/E5TGy/

Regarding the "correct" way to make it work with arrays, the whole concept is not appropriate to this problem. It doesn't make sense to have an array where the value stored at index `i` *is* `i` the way you do - if looking up `myimage[7]` gives you `7` what's the point? The nearest thing to your code that will work is something like this:

```
document.write('<img id="' + myimage[i] +
               '" src="pic_bulboff.gif" onmouseover="changeImage(' + myimage[i] + 
               ')" width="20" height="36" />');
```

...and then your function would be:

```
function changeImage(elementID) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
    if (element.src.match("bulbon")) {
        element.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    }
    else {
        element.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}
```

As shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/qKksU/

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply @nnnnnn. I used your first version solution, but there was no image appeared at all. I just past your code to replace my code. is there any syntax issues?

Comment: BTW, since I have spent so many time on my array version solution, I kind want to know the correct syntax for \\ element = document.getElementById(myimage[i]);\\ and \\document.write("<img id=\"myimage[i]\"......); \\   do you know the correct way to type these? @nnnnnn